# iOS 11 [MediaRemote] [AVOutputContext] WARNING: AVF context unavailable for MRAVOutputContextCreateIndependentRoutingContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

I use video player (framework MediaPlayer) in iOS application. 
If I rotate device to landscape orientation, video doesn't rotate to landscape.

There is no video rotation only on iOS 11. iOS 9, 10 - rotates good.

Before start video player and when device is rotating, XCode get message:

```
[MediaRemote] [AVOutputContext] WARNING: AVF context unavailable for MRAVOutputContextCreateIndependentRoutingContext
```

What to do for rotating video?

Answer (score -1):

When I delete all the breakpoints，my problem was fixed. Maybe you can try that and hope it also gets fixed for you.

[image]